# Styling Superfish menu with Zen and Sass

Tags: navigation, theming

Can anyone advise on the best way to style your superfish menu when using latest version of zen and sass? 
I am currently styling my responsive theme using the sass files which regenerate the css, which is going great, but superfish comes with its own set of css files which are located sites/all/libraries/superfish/style/css.

I ideally want to use sass to style it from my sass folder (under theme root) so its all consistent, so I dont have to keep changing into the supefish folder changing css directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Zen is organized according to the [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) way. However, what SMACCS calls modules is called components in Zen. This to avoid confusion, since Drupal already has a definition for 'modules'. SMACSS defines modules (or components in Zen) as follows:

*..Module is a more discrete component of the page. It is your navigation bars and your carousels and your dialogs and your widgets and so on...*[source](http://smacss.com/book/type-module)

All SASS code concerning components is stored therefore in `your_zen_subtheme/sass/components/_misc.scss` file. I would choose to add style rules for your Superfish menu there. You can use the Superfish classes (with the `.sf` prefix) to target only the Superfish menu instead of all menus.

Comment: You don't have to add many CSS changes to override the super fish entries. As Sydney says, Zen 5 uses SMACSS to provide a modular organization. I would add a _navbar.scss module (component) rather than edit _misc.scss . In fact, the new Zen6 has been refactored to be much more modular, following the Drupal 8 SMACSS best practices.